# What are examples of pseudorandom functions that can be preformed without the assistance of a computer?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, random, function-and-relation-composition

I'm trying to generate a **seemingly** random list of integers *without* the use of a computational device; one capable of being unraveled with a mathematical function. What's the best way to devise a complex function algorithm that produces seemingly unrelated results? My goal is to be able to create a list of numbers (e.g. 327965184) that look as if they can't be related in any way, but can be solved one by one by plugging in sequential numbers (for x) in an f(x) function (e.g. f(1)=3, f(2)=2, f(3)=7).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Best" is quite vague but the term for what you are looking for is a psydorandom function.

Comment: You can pick a choice from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators) and take a look at [some tests](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html) that access how random are the numbers coming from them. oooooh without a computer?

Comment: Why the "without the assistance of a computer?" If you have an algorithm, then any computing device, including a human, can follow the steps of the algorithm to perform the computation. In other words, you should be asking for an algorithm. No need to mention computers.

Comment: It appears that what you want is actually an seemingly random permutation. In that case, there is no need for a function $f(x)$.

Comment: Flip a coin:  $H$ means $0-4$, $T$ means $5-9$.  Then role a single die, ignoring any $6$ and mapping the die value to the digit you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a particular favorite of mine: it requires some math, but is pretty manageable by hand.

Take a random seed of length $n$, and square it, and then pull out the middle $n$ digits of $n^2$ to serve as the next number in the pseudorandom sequence.